# Plot graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the graph between 'Z' and 'SigM'. I'm getting an error. Could anyone please help in plotting the graph.

```
K = 1
Rmv = 26
SigS = 111.7
M = 2.050
N = 2
SigD = (-249.4)
def Mittelspannung():
    result = [] 
    Z = []
    SigM = []
    for i in range(1,31):
        output = 1 - pow((((i-1)*1/14.5)-1),2)
        result.append(output)
        #print(output)   
    for value in range(0,15):
        C4 = (Rmv) - (result[value]) * (Rmv)
        Z.append(C4)
        print(C4)    
    for value in range(15,30):                
        B11 = (SigD) - (result[value]) * (SigD)
        Z.append(B11)
        print(B11)           
    for x in range(0,30):    
        SigMean = ((SigS**M * (1-(Z[x] + SigS)**N/(Rmv + SigS)**N))*(1/M))/K
        SigM.append(SigMean) 
    return SigM
print(Mittelspannung())
```

> 43 return Z, SigM ---> 44 plot.plot(Z, SigM) 45 plot.show() 46 print(Mittelspannung()) NameError: name 'Z' is not define

Comment: Could you provide the error message? It is hard to understand the issue without the actual problem.

Comment: You commented out the definition of `Z`  in your first for loop. That's why it's not defined. But that does not fix the issue, as you're trying to access `Z` like it's an iterator in your last for loop, but it's actually of type float. So you're having some issues with your `Z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a list `Z` in which you are going to append the Z values computed at each iteration, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

K = 1
Rmv = 26
SigS = 111.7
M = 2.050
N = 2
SigD = (-249.4)

def Mittelspannung():
    result = [] 
    Y = []
    SigM = []
    Z = []

    for i in range(1,31):
        output = 1 - pow((((i-1)*1/14.5)-1),2)
        Z.append(Rmv - (output*Rmv))
        result.append(output)
    
    for value in range(0,15):
        C4 = (Rmv) - (result[value]) * (Rmv)
        Y.append(C4)   

    for value in range(15,30):                
        B11 = (SigD) - (result[value]) * (SigD)
        Y.append(B11)
          
    for x in range(0,30):    
        SigMean = ((SigS**M * (1-(Z[x] + SigS)**N/(Rmv + SigS)**N))**(1/M)) / K
        SigM.append(SigMean) 
    return Z, SigM


Z, SigM = Mittelspannung()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(Z, SigM)
```

Comment: I have posted a question regarding Optimization. Could you please help me.

Comment: Sure, in the meantime mark this answer as the solution to this question!

Comment: Yeah, sure @Davide_sd

Comment: I'm eagerly waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for deselecting my answer, which by the way, was the first to be posted and the more accurate as it presented CODE.

Comment: I haven't deselected your answer. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define Z in the function call. Depending on what tool your using, you should be able to see that in the error message, something like "Z is being used before initializing".

Comment: Thank you so much, the code is working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
Z, SigM = Mittelspannung()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(Z, SigM)
```

this code will show you the error

> #error

```
----> 1 Z, SigM = Mittelspannung()
      2 plt.figure()
      3 plt.plot(Z, SigM)
```

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

// Try this one

```
SigM = Mittelspannung()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(SigM)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).